# glyph icon in html select not working

Tags: php, html, font-awesome, glyphicons

I am trying to get a from select to display a glyp icon before the category name.  The category name shows fine.  I cannot get the glyph icon to show up.  It works outside the option, but cannot get the icon into the drop down menu.

Thanks in advance. Here is where I am at

```
<option \>Select</option>
  <?php
do {  
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_event_cats['cat_id']?>"><i class="fa fa-leaf"></i><?php     echo $row_event_cats['cat_name']?></option>
  <?php
} while ($row_event_cats = mysql_fetch_assoc($event_cats));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($event_cats);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($event_cats, 0);
      $row_event_cats = mysql_fetch_assoc($event_cats);
  }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropdown menu will only display text. But the Glyphicon tag `<i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>` contains no text, so it won't be displayed. You can maybe try to find a glyph library which actually uses chars and not class, but I can't think of any rght now. Let me search a few seconds.

**EDIT**

It appears that it is impossible to do with the "standard" HTML toolkit. If you're using Bootstrap, check http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

If you're not, check http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: It does have a value of "UTF+E002" but i am unsure of how to implement this.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Seems like you will have to look at this: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
Because doing it in "native" HTML seems pretty tough.

Comment: Yes using Bootstrap.  I will check out the select2

Comment: If you're working with Bootstrap, you'd be better off with this I think: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/
Check the end of the examples section.

Comment: _"Accept"_ in Stack Overflow means checking the sort of "OK" symbol right below the up and down vote buttons for an answer. By doing this, you will flag this answer as "helpful" for the next people having the same problem as you, and reading your post. Check this for a more in-depth explanation of how Stack Overflow works: [Stack Overflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Cheers! :)